# Retrieving Integer Data from an NSMutable Array

Tags: xcode, nsmutablearray, integer

I am having an issue getting integer values form an NSMutable array.  I have several buttons on the screen with a matching tag property value (button1 has a tag value of 1, etc.).  When a button is pressed, I add the numeric tag value to the NSMutable array.  Later, I want to loop through the objects to see what values are pressed to build a query.  However, Iget a SIGABRT error in the loop.

```
//pairNumber is the 'tag' value from a button
-(void) numberSearchArray:(NSInteger)pairNumber;
{
    [self.queryPairs addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: pairNumber]];
}

//***************************

-(void)buildQuery:(BOOL *)function numberToUse:(NSInteger)number
{
   //other code not shown

   int pair_values [6];
   int compare_total = [queryPairs count];

   for (int x = 0; x<=compare_total-1; x++){
     pair_values[x] = (NSUInteger)[queryPairs objectAtIndex:x];  //SIGABRT error

   //code continued...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do:

```
[[queryPairs objectAtIndex:x] intValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not bounds checking pair_values, do you have more than 6 items in your queryPairs array?